# Error in the following JScript code?

Tags: javascript, xml

Below is a code for an html application(hta). Could you point out th error in the following code? The error reported is "object required, line 13, char 1." Am new to JScript, so don't know much, and I've been wrestling with this for some time. And the "tech.htm" is a Wikipedia page on topic Technology, saved in my D Drive.
The same code works for some RSS feed pages and the content is saved successfully to LogFile.txt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<html>
<body>
<h1> The text.</h1>
<script type = "text/javascript">

var xml_doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
xml_doc.async = false;
xml_doc.load("D:\\tech.htm");
var txt = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName("p");
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("D:\\LogFile.txt",true);
s.WriteLine(txt.item(2).text);
document.write("<p>2+@</p>");

</script>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot load HTML into an XML object. Very likely it's already failing at the `xml_doc.load` line. Tip: Make your jScript code work in a `.js` file that you execute on the command line with `cscript.exe`. This makes debugging easier. Once it works there, you can include it 1:1 in an HTA application via a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the tech.htm file cannot be parsed as valid XML. Try adding these line in your code:

```
alert(xml_dox.parseError);
alert(txt.length);
```

- If the first one returns different than 0, then D:\tech.htm is not well-formed XML;
- If the second returns less than 3, the file doesn't contain three P elements.

Answer (score 1):

If my count is correct, the error is from the line:

```
s.WriteLine(txt.item(2).text);
```

Not having access to the html file, i would guess that there are not 3 p tags on the page.